# How does Amazon RDS dns resolution work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-rds, amazon-route53

Amazon provide you a url of form like x.y.us-west-4.rds.amazonaws.com . Whenever you try to connect to database server first this dns name should get resolved.After dns resolution you get an IP address(static is guess) and you try to connect to this IP address.

There are lots of RDS servers globally. It's not possible to assign all of them an static IP. So how does amazon manage all this with limited no. of IPs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have some incorrect information about RDS, and perhaps about the scale of AWS.

Amazon [publishes their IP address ranges](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) and on that list, you'll find that AWS holds over 5 million IP addresses in the us-east-1 region, alone, so, yes, it's possible to assign each RDS instance a static IP address, and that's exactly how it works.

> there are lots of RDS servers globally

Well, yes and no.  "Globally" isn't all that relevant, since RDS is a regional service... and your RDS instance is running, by itself, on exactly one virtual machine, which did not exist until it was launched when you requested an RDS instance, and it's physically located in exactly one availability zone.

When it was launched, it was assigned a static IP address, and the DNS entry was created, pointing there.

Additionally, of course, RDS instances can be launched into VPC without a public IP address.

In any event, the MySQL wire protocol has no provision for passing a hostname in-band.  HTTP has this (in the `Host:` header) and HTTPS has this (in the SNI extension in TLS) but unlike those protocols, it is impossible to use the hostname to identify the appropriate back-end on a MySQL connection, so multiple hostnames accessing different services behind a single IP address or pool, identified by the hostname can't be done.

Comment: Thanks!
There are many blogs on blogspot.com like x.blogspot.com. x can be anything. I don't think they resolve each subdomain to a unique ip.Can you please help me on it too?

Comment: That's HTTP -- a very different protocol than the one used by MySQL.  I wondered if, perhaps, you were actually asking something different than the literal question you posed.  For web sites, in DNS, you can point `*.example.com` to a single IP address, and `${anything}.example.com` will route there.  The server can then inspect the `Host:` header in the HTTP request to decide which content to serve, or, if the server is a reverse proxy like HAProxy, it can choose a back-end server (or group of servers) based on the contents of the `Host:` header, which the browser sends with each request.